# Resize parent by moving splitter

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, devexpress, splitter

i have a question about resizing.

I know the function of a splitter is to split some elements in the form without resizing the parent. The splitter splits the 100% of the parentsize in e.g. 40% and 60%. But in my case i need a splitter or something like that, which resize the parent (UserControl) and not the other element (Panel).

For example i have 2 panels with the height of 50px and 50px. Between them there is a splitter which resizes now one panel to 70px. The second panel should keep the 50px and the UserControl should resize to 120px.

Furthermore in my application the UserControl is added to a panel with autoscroll = true to show a vertical scrollbar. Does anyone have an idea to realize this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try coding some action inside the splitter event that will change your window size. However it is counter intuitive (does not follow standard windows ui) that a window will resize following an action from the inside. 
Consider setting your grid row definitions in a way that only the top one resizes when then window is resized. e.g. below for columns. the example is from a working real page that does what you asked (the columns on the right side are not squeezed or stretched when the windows is resized). Note that the splitters in the actual page xaml are far below (after all the content panels).

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="ThirdCol0" Width="353"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="ThirdCol1" Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="ThirdCol2" Width="*" MaxWidth="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="ThirdCol3" Width="117" MaxWidth="267"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- here there are different panels etc -->

        <GridSplitter x:Name="MidSplitter"    DragCompleted="MidSplitter_DragCompleted" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
            Width="5" Opacity="0.2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
             ShowsPreview="False"></GridSplitter>
        <GridSplitter x:Name="Col2Splitter"  DragCompleted="MidSplitter_DragCompleted"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
            Width="5" Opacity="0.2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
             ShowsPreview="False"></GridSplitter>
        <GridSplitter  DragCompleted="MidSplitter_DragCompleted" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  
            Width="5"  Opacity="0.2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
             ShowsPreview="False"></GridSplitter>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is about WinForms, not WPF.

Answer (score 0):

When the size of your user control changes, you need :

- the panel1 to be resized
- the panel2 to keep its height unchanged

Am I right ?

In this case, you don't need to use a splitter, but the Dock property of Controls :

- Set the `panel1.Dock` property to `DockStyle.Fill` : the panel1 will take all available space in the UserControl
- Set the `panel2.Dock` property to `DockStyle.Bottom` : the panel2 will keep its initial height to stay at the bottom of the UserControl

I hope it helps.

Comment: I set them to Top and Fill. However i tested your settings, but it did not change the behaviour. What did you mean with "you don't need to use a splitter"? How shall the user resize the panels?

Comment: @MarcelD Traditionally, if the UserControl is going to change size at all, you should be dragging an outside edge- not an edge that is *inside* the UserControl.